# Combine select and update statement in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, set, zero

I would like to set all blank columns of my query to "0", so that I can use it for further calculations.

My query looks as follows:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Erstattungen.Betrag) AS Gesamtbetrag_Erstattungen,
    Mitarbeiter.Referent_Name
FROM 
    Mitarbeiter 
LEFT JOIN 
    Erstattungen ON Mitarbeiter.Mitarbeiter_ID = Erstattungen.Mitarbeiter_ID
GROUP BY 
    Mitarbeiter.Referent_Name, Erstattungen.Mitarbeiter_ID;
```

and it returns empty columns for `Gesamtbetrag_Erstattungen` as a result of the left join.

I would like to fill these empty columns with "0" instead of having a blank space there.

What would be a good way to do that? Maybe use an additional update function? How could I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "empty" fields are `NULL`s caused by the `LEFT JOIN`.  Because of the `LEFT JOIN`, all aggregation columns should come from the first table.

You can then use `NZ()` to replace the values:

```
SELECT NZ(Sum(e.Betrag), 0) AS Gesamtbetrag_Erstattungen, m.Referent_Name
FROM Mitarbeiter as m LEFT JOIN
     Erstattungen as e
     ON m.Mitarbeiter_ID = e.Mitarbeiter_ID
GROUP BY m.Referent_Name, m.Mitarbeiter_ID;
```

Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.  Note the change to using `m.Mitarbeiter_ID` instead of `e.Mitarbeiter_ID` and `NZ()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm!
Just one question, it transforms the values into number format, although i would like to have it in a currency format with "€" behind it.
Should I change that in the query ot rather in the report i use it after? And how could i manage that?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @balisto91 . . . I would suggest adding the currency segment in the application.  You can concatenate it in the query as well, but that seems more of a presentation issue.